# Why are light rays able to cross each other?

Tags: visible-light, image-processing

See the image first: [image: See the image]

Why are light rays able to cross each other? Air isn't able to.

Comment: Water waves can [cross each other](http://www.uq.edu.au/_School_Science_Lessons/25.3.9.JPG). This is more or less what light waves crossing would look like if you magnified them enough.

Comment: @PeterShor ...that's probably for small amplitude. As for large amplitudes water waves are non-linear and they do [interact](https://www.witpress.com/books/978-1-85312-545-4)

Comment: @mikuszefski: I'm probably being too pedantic here, but the same is true for light (although the amplitudes here probably need to be truly enormous). Consider sending a lot of photons from all directions towards one spot: they'll form a black hole.

Comment: @PeterShor ...so related to [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22876/does-a-photon-exert-a-gravitational-pull) PE question.... sort of funny, indeed.

Comment: @mikuszefski You are both correct, Peter only points out the waves can cross each other, not that they don't interact at all but you are correct in that the water waves do interact.

Comment: @PeterShor Schlieren photographs might display air wave interference, I am not sure but maybe https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlieren_photography. Just FYI

Comment: @LioElbammalf I consider "crossing each other" as not interacting, otherwise a lot of things can cross each other under the right circumstances, a bullet can cross a wall, e.g.

Comment: @PeterShor  bad example.   Water waves are the result of energy being transferred from molecule to molecule.  Light waves are a conceptual representation of the propagation of photons -- or if you prefer, the probabalistic propagation of a high-frequency electromagnetic field.  There is no ether.

Comment: @Carl: it doesn't matter!!! Low amplitude water waves pass through each other just like light waves. And demonstrate interference just like light waves.

Comment: @PeterShor Just because it looks the same doesn't mean it is the same, and the question was specifically **how** light is able to do this.

Comment: Why questions like this are notoriously difficult for physics because science doesn't explain "why." When you ask a physicist why something happens, what we give you instead is an explanation of the phenomena using a more general theory, or we tie it to a mathematical model and studies showing that model's validity. For example, we could explain this behavior of light by explaining it in quantum mechanics terms, or we could say "light acts like a wave" and discuss the mathematical behavior of waves. Can you give us anything to help us figure out what you are looking for from a "why" question?

Comment: Waves in air - that is, sound - certainly can and do cross each other.  You can hear sounds from multiple sources, and can usually distinguish the source of a particular sound, or separate out one person's voice in a noisy room...

Comment: The picture above doesn't really 'show' light waves crossing each other.

Comment: @Physicist: I don't understand your comment. I don't doubt that it is a real picture, but where does it show light waves crossing each other? The pattern shown is the scattering & reflection of the source rays by the underlying surface. Your questions is a reasonable one and light rays do cross, but the picture doesn't demonstrate light rays crossing each other.

Comment: Answers are protected but the answer is this: Waves are transmitted through a MEDIUM but the medium doesn't travel from the origin to the destination of the wave. If the medium were travelling then it would bounce off.  Waves on the sea pass through each other, but if you sent two jets of sea water into collision, they would bounce off.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1361/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Physicist Do not make make edits to your post which do not substantially improve it. Trivial edits of your own material have the effect of pushing other people's material off of the front page, which makes it harder for them to get their questions answered.

Comment: OK I'll remember.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Note: this answer was in response to the original question:

*My question is that Why the light rays able to cross each other weather **water waves** and **air** could not cross each other*

Other waves pass through each other just as with light. This is easy to test. Place four people at the corner of a large room. Have two of them, at adjacent corners talk to the person at a diagonal corner. Use a cone such as a cheerleader might use to somewhat channel the sound. You may be a bit distracted by the other voice but you will clearly hear the voice from the opposite corner.

Here's a standard demo in a high school science class. Have two students hold each end of a moderately stretched slinky resting on a smooth floor. Have each student give the slinky a sharp snap to their right. Since the students are facing each other, the pulses will be opposite one another as they travel toward opposite ends. When the two pulses meet in the middle the slinky will appear relatively straight but only for an instant. The two pulses will continue to travel past one another as if they never had met.

Waves of the same kind traveling through one another maintain their original identity after the encounter. This is a basic property of waves, you can read about it in any introductory Physics text.

Comment: Bad answer even though it appears simple.   Light waves simply are not like any kind of physical (water, acoustic) waves.

Comment: We need some moderators to fix this rating -- it's a case of too many nonphysicists upvoting a false answer.   Reminds me, sadly, of the time when  (some) math PhDs angrily denounced the correct answer to the Monty Hall problem.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft. Rude and inappropriate. This was answered in context of the original question before it was edited. My intrepretation was the focus on why other waves do not appear to pass through one another like light. I taught Physics for 24 years, quite successfully by most measures.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I think this answer is good. Light waves may be made of different things than sound waves, but they pass through each other for the same reason: because they can be modeled as linear equations.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft For the record, moderators cannot influence the voting total on any post except by voting on it themselves like any other user. Also, could you elaborate on why you think the analogy to other waves is "false"? To me, it's simply a result of the wave equation (no matter for what type of wave) being linear, so two different solutions just superpose instead of altering each other.

Comment: Yes, linearity comes to mind but I dont think it would be god answerhere. Maybe something that we can imagine in some way? More pictorial answer with some physical intuition?

Answer (score 17):

I believe it's because you are thinking of the light as particles (little solid balls) that it seems a bit odd that "they can pass through each other." I think thinking in terms of (quantum) fields gets rid of this. As someone mentioned, photons are bosons and so there is no Pauli exclusion principle that applies to them. That is to say, they can be at the same place at the same time....so the fact that they can "pass through" each other seems less odd, knowing that.

Said more simply, the information of the photons spreads out, and there is nothing to prohibit this information from allowing the photons to cross the same point in space at the same time. This is easier to see if you know math and look at the equations explaining photons.

*Note: We are neglecting any interactions between photons in this sort of explanation.

Answer (score 11):

You seem to be looking for a more mathematically oriented answer, so let's try that. You **cannot** prove that light rays are able to cross each other because that is **false**: it only works in the approximation of very dim light. If you were to take your source of light and increase the frequency or amplitude of the electric field, you'd observe a non-linear behaviour: rays would very clearly influence each other as the pass through each other.

The key aspect of the superposition principle is linearity, that is, the fact that Maxwell's equations are linear. If you consider electromagnetic radiation in a certain material, it is well-known that for intense enough radiation the polarisation becomes non-linear, and you enter the realm of [nonlinear optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics). Here, the polarisation $\boldsymbol P$ becomes a (non-linear) function of $\boldsymbol E$, and therefore the wave equation becomes
$$
\left(\nabla\times\nabla\times+\frac{n^2}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)\boldsymbol E=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\boldsymbol P(\boldsymbol E)
$$
which is a non-linear equation for $\boldsymbol E$. For example, a very strong source of light (travelling through the air) the [Kerr effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_effect) or other non-linear effects kick in. This is due to quadratic (and higher) terms in the polarisation tensor $\boldsymbol P\sim\chi_1\boldsymbol E+\chi_2\boldsymbol E\otimes\boldsymbol E+\cdots$.

The polarisation of realistic materials is **always** non-linear, and therefore light rays **always** influence each other. Only in the limit $\chi_2E^2\ll \chi_1E$ the wave equation becomes linear; in other words, only in the limit of very weak radiation are light rays oblivious to other light rays.

Even in vacuum you can observe non-linear behaviour. The Maxwell Lagrangian, corrected by quantum-mechanical effects, becomes
$$
\mathcal L=\frac12(\boldsymbol E^2-\boldsymbol B^2)+\frac{2\alpha}{45m^4}\left[(\boldsymbol E^2-\boldsymbol B^2)^2+7(\boldsymbol E\cdot\boldsymbol B)^2\right]
$$
where $\alpha\sim 1/137$ is the fine-structure constant, and $m$ is the mass of the electron. As $\mathcal L$ is non-linear in $\boldsymbol E,\boldsymbol B$, the propagation of electromangetic waves is no longer linear, and the superposition principle ceases to hold. Only when you can neglect the non-linear terms the superposition principle becomes valid.

In a nutshell, your question is based on a false premise. Light rays seem to be able to cross each other and continue their path unaffected, but this is because you are not using sensitive enough instruments (e.g., your eyes). If you were to measure the effect of light rays on each other with a very good piece of equipment, you'd observe that they do affect each other, both in a material and in vacuum.

Comment: maybe you could use this link http://www.conspiracyoflight.com/LaserInterference/LaserInterference.html

Comment: Can you give a reference for the second equation?

Comment: @knzhou it's the [Euler–Heisenberg Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Heisenberg_Lagrangian).

Answer (score 9):

> Why are the light rays able to cross each other

The underlying level of nature is quantum mechanical. Light is an emergent phenomenon from the quantum mechanical level of photons, where an enormous number of photons of energy $h\nu$ build up the classical electromagnetic wave which is light.

Photon–photon interactions are very very rare at energies below twice the mass of an electron . [The quantum mechanical feynman diagram](https://www.quora.com/Can-two-photons-collide) of two photons interacting, from which the probability of interaction can be calculated:

[image: two photon]

has four electromagnetic vertices, i.e. (1/137)^1/2  for the amplitude, and when squared as it multiplies the integral for the probability, the number becomes miniscule, so photon photon interactions are very rare. As the answer by @AccidentalFourierTransform states, using classical electromagnetic waves, some interaction can happen, but it would need very good instrumentation to see it.

One can see interference between two light beams, but interference is not interaction, it comes from the superposition of two beams collective wavefunctions, which when detected show the interference pattern from the way the photons' wave functions  build up the macroscopic light beam. Superposition is not interaction, so the beams can cross and continue on their way, if a detector is not introduced in the overlap.(Note that anyway, to see [interference patterns](http://www.conspiracyoflight.com/LaserInterference/LaserInterference.html) one should have coherent monochromatic beams).

For high energy photons other channels open with higher probability, but that is another story.

Comment: From your statement: "... photons of energy hν build up" can I take it that an individual photon has a frequency and therefore a 'colour'? If so how does this (do these) transform into the " ...  classical electromagnetic wave which is light."? If you can point me in the right direction I'd be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnP The photon when measured can only give information for spin (+/-1) and energy.BUT as a quantum mecanical entity it is described by a wavefunction which is a solution of the quantized maxwell equations, see this https://arxiv.org/ftp/quant-ph/papers/0604/0604169.pdf .  The way the classical field is build from QED can be seen here  http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html . the image here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_angular_momentum_of_light may help

Comment: A small correction perhaps: one needs two vertices to get one factor of $\alpha$, right? So, doesn't four vertices give two factors of $\alpha$?

Comment: @flippiefanus  I was using the "fundamental forces"  number http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/couple.html  and according to http://www-pnp.physics.ox.ac.uk/~barra/teaching/feynman.pdf this is already squared. I edited , thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is no force which could act between two photons so they cannot* interact with each other to cause interference.

*At least for the most part, [it is possible for them to cause interference via decay to other particles.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics)

Comment: Isn't this contradicted by the double-slit experiment?

Comment: It is a good point, one I don't fully have the answer to at the moment. I think the result of that experiment has some sort of dependence on the uncertainty as to which slit the photon travels through rather than interaction between the photons. I think it is the superposition of the two possibilities of the same photon that interfere. I'm not 100% on this though, my QM is a little rusty.

Comment: @wizzwizz4  No, the double-slit experiment, extended, has conclusively shown that each photon interferes with itself.  It's just a simplified model of light as interfering wavefronts that we use to keep non-physicists' heads from exploding.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft: two different photons can interfere with each other, as well. It's just that demonstrating this is a lot more complicated because you somehow have to synchronize their phases.

Comment: @PeterShor no,  photons do not interfere with each other, or to be more precise, the quantum mechanical probability (remember  $<\psi|$  and $|\xi>$ stuff?) is down by a factor of$ c^2$

Comment: As an aside I would not characterize light-light interactions as a decay.

Comment: @dmckee This is, perhaps, a misunderstanding on my part. I had thought the photon must first produce another particle in order to interact and, to conserve relevant quantum numbers they must produce a second particle too. (I admit this explanation has got away from me a little so this may not make sense) But the number of photons cannot be constant at every stage so I assumed a decay must take place.
A feynman diagram would be best but I'll have to settle for: $\gamma ->f \bar{f}$ is what I am imagining, with the fermions being the particles which interact with our second photon.

Comment: @Carl: Please google "two-photon interference", and explain to me why all these experimentalists with published papers are ***wrong***. They don't interact with each other very strongly, but interaction and interference are different things.

Comment: Ah, well,  I sort of knew dropping in on this question was an exercise in https://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: @Elbamath: Two photons don't interact with each other (except at incredibly high energies), so two light beams can pass through each other. Two photons can interfere with each other, but that doesn't stop them two photon beams from passing through each other. (Just like water waves from two different directions exhibit interference when passing through each other).

Comment: @PeterShor I'm not entirely sure of the mechanism but I think you must be right on the interference because of LIGO, they have two entirely separate beams which interfere with one another so the probability argument I had been using for the double slit experiment doesn't hold up. Thanks for keeping me questioning it. Do you know what the mechanism for the interference is? (In fact I think this is a question all of it's own, I may make one)

Comment: [This question already exists, with an answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90608/if-photons-dont-interact-directly-how-can-electromagnetic-waves-interfere)

Comment: @PeterShor could it be that two photons do not interact until being absorbed by matter. In other words you see the effect of multiple photons impacting atoms on the surface or detection screen.

Comment: @Bill: I suppose it could be. After all, you never detect the photons until they interact with matter. In Hong-Ou-Mandel interference, I think it makes more sense if you consider the photon interference to occur in the beam splitter and not in the photodetector. But other people might have different intuition.

Answer (score 2):

Because the light consists of photons. And photons are Bosons (not like for example electrons, which are Fermions. Bosons and Fermions obey different laws (search for Fermi-Dirac statistics and Bose-Einstein statistic on Wikipedia for more info). In short and mundaine words: Fermions can not be in the same place at the same time, but Bosons can. This is why light rays go through each other.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Fermion or Boson. Bosons can easily interact via electric charge etc.

Comment: @mikuszefski  but it does have to do with Bosons having integral spin.

Comment: All the waves or wavelike stuff can be interpreted as bosons, like phonons in a crystal...

Comment: Light beams passing through each other necessarily have different momenta so exclusion never comes up: they are not trying to be in the same state (because the state space is the Hamiltonian phase-space: both position and momentum matter).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft well that's sort of the definition of a Boson, is it not? Nevertheless, that does not exclude fermions from crossing, as this means they move in different directions. The momenta are, hence, not equal such that they can be at the same position without violating Pauli's principle.

Answer (score 2):

A small addition to other answers. Light is both a wave and a particle, called [Wave-particle Duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality). Basically, It acts like both a Wave and a Particle. Its very complicated to get into, and I cant properly describe when it acts like what in all situations, but there are a few that are relevant here. First off, Air is a particle, or rather, many many particles. As such, Like you described, they can not cross eachother. What we have found though, is that Light does not act like a particle in that aspect, It acts like a wave. Peter Shor's comment links to this [image showing this in water](http://www.uq.edu.au/_School_Science_Lessons/25.3.9.JPG), which shows how waves act when they cross over each other. This is called [Interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_(wave_propagation)). When 2 waves cross, they interfere with eachother, changing the total size of the wave. 2 waves can stack on each other, becoming twice as tall, or they meet each others low points, and flatten out. They could do both, and everything in between, but they will not stop moving because of this meeting. The Interference link above to the Wiki page has some good animations of it in action.

Light will act in the same way. and this is most easily shown by the famous [Double Slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment). There are numerous youtube videos animating this, such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfPeprQ7oGc) one, which shows that light, when passing through 2 slits, will hit a wall with the exact same pattern as waves of water would in the same situation, and this pattern is called the Interference pattern. It also shows off the Wave-Particle Duality, because when you actually monitor the light to determine how it passes through the slits, it acts like a particle, but that is a whole other question.